# Using a variable within AngularJS expression?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular, but I was wondering am I able to use a JS variable within an AngularJS expression (not sure if it's called an expression).
The simplest way I can demonstrate is this:

```
<code>
    <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var number = 10;
    </script>
    <div ng-app="">
        <p>My expression: {{ 5 + number}}</p>
    </div>
</code>
```

Is there a way I do this?

Comment: Why do you have variables existing outside controllers/services/etc ?

Comment: No, it's impossible.

Comment: cant be done. But if you're really desperate you can have "number" in window object and in your controller can do something like $scope.number = window.number and then use it. Wont suggest that though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot use global variables (or functions) in Angular expressions. Angular expressions are just attributes, so are strings and not Javascript code. Angular parser ([`$parse`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) service, [sourse code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/parse.js)) takes those attributes, parses them and evaluates against scope object of the Angular app. So in order to use anything in Angular expression it must be defined on the corresponding scope object.

Comment: Thanks for that. But are you able to direct me in how I would go about doing the following. In [link](http://jsfiddle.net/0e9j5wev/6/), i need to be able to use different strings (eg. 'GoPro' - which is used in the example). So when a product is clicked the specific content of that product is displayed '{{ products[0].GoPro.Description }}'. Help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to. You are going to kill the whole purpose of Angular if you do so. And won't work how you put it. 
Still I made a Plunker for you here. After all a global JavaScript variable can be access from inside your controller if it was defined before your controller code.It is all JavaScript after all

http://plnkr.co/edit/LiwvNd4Nf5lW0HUsSyyq?p=preview

in HTML

```
<script>
  var x = 7;
</script>
```

and in controller

```
// in the controller
    $scope.Foo=function(){
      return $scope.Page + x;
    }
```