# Convert an express-like string to an expression in Angular view

Tags: angularjs, expression

Assuming that I have an expression-like string in my scope

`$scope.expressionString = 'model.key == "anything"'`

I want to use this string as an expression in view, can I do that?

In view, I will have something like

`<div ng-if="expressionString"></div>` but of course, expressionString should be something else instead.

I appreciate any help. Cheers!

Comment: Isn't `'model.key' == 'anything'` always `false`?

Comment: I think you want to do something like this: `$scope.expressionString = 'model.key';` and in your view: `<div ng-if="expressionString == 'anything'">...</div>`

Comment: Can you provide further explanation? If your expressionString is literally a string and not a boolean, it will evaluate as true in the ng-if simply because it exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$eval` to evaluate your expression , there are two ways to do it in your case

**Solution 1**

```
 <div ng-if="$eval(expressionString)"></div>
```

**Solution 2**

In the controller store the evaluated value of the expression like below

```
  $scope.expressionString = $scope.$eval('model.key == "anything"')
```

and then in the view simply use it without using $eval in the view

```
 <div ng-if="expressionString"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, we don't want to do anything inside the controller because the string is pulled from the database and sometimes it exists, sometimes it doesn't. Do you have any opinion about this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38299131/1974153

Comment: So use the first solution where you don't have to do anything in the controller...

Comment: I see, thank you very much for explaining. I thought in order to use $eval or $parse you need to inject them into view somehow (through controller for example), but I was wrong. Will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use global variables (or functions) in Angular expressions. Angular expressions are just attributes, so are strings and not Javascript code.

[Please see this stackoverflow answer once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30829258/2815219)

Although, you can achieve it using a function instead of a variable:

```
  $scope.expressionString = function(toCompare) {
    return $scope.model.key == toCompare;
  }
```

and in your view:

```
<div ng-if="expressionString('anything')"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the problem is the string is pulled from the database. And we don't want to process it in our controller.

Comment: How is string pulled? `JSP`? 
I've modified my answer according to that. See if it works

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, made a `parse` filter to parse the string and assign it a scope

```js
angular.module('zehitomo')
.filter('parse', function ($parse) {
  return function (expression, scope) {
    return $parse(expression)(scope);
  };
});
```

And in view

`ng-if="expressionString | parse:this"`

Comment: Why to create an additional filter for it...and you are using $parse only in that filter..angular has already given you a function on the scope level to achieve the same thing which also uses $parse only internally..then why to create one of your own.

Comment: When you see the definition of $eval, you will find that it is using $parse only.